# GLIBCXX_3.4.19 not found

Tags: cross-compilation, c++

I am trying to run a program, written in C++ using the new C++11 standard.
I use Code::Blocks on my PC and cross-compile for the Raspberry Pi using these tools: https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/. Everything worked OK, until I added some functions.
I was using `std::condition_variable::wait` and it worked fine until I tried to use `std::condition_variable::wait_for`, which does compile, but when I try to run it on the Raspberry, it prints

```
./OPUI: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by ./OPUI)
```

and dies (OPUI is the name of my program).

Does this mean that I cannot use these functions? If so - which functions are and which are not usable and how do I know?

Thanks!